# Python - print until marker (a la PHP)?

Tags: python, escaping, heredoc

In PHP I can do this:

```
print <<<END
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines
END;
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Python?

I want to dump a big chunk of HTML without worrying about escaping e.g. angle brackets.

Comment: "without worrying about escaping"?  What?  What escaping are you worried about?  Python is not PHP and isn't embedded into a web page where <, > and & matter.  What are you asking about?

Comment: I'm thinking of escaping anything that might be treated non-verbatim by the python parser. Quotes maybe? Anyway, I think @Mark 's answer is what I'm looking for.

Comment: "Quotes maybe?"  Maybe?  What kind of quotes are you having problems with?   What Python Tutorial are you using?  This is well, well covered in almost every tutorial.  Please provide the title or a link to the tutorial you're using that omitted mention of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't have heredocs with arbitrary start/end markers. You can use triple quotes (either single or double) to achieve something very similar:

```
print '''
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines
'''
```

Add an `r` to make it a raw string so that backslash is also not treated specially. `r'''....'''`

Comment: The difference is you start with \n here.

Comment: @Antoine Pelisse: The newline can be omitted, but doing so destroys the nice left-aligned layout in the source code. You could remove the unneeded newlines at runtime using a strip but then it would decrease performance. You could use a backslash on the firstline to escape the new line `'''\ ` but then you can't use a raw-string. So in short the answer is 'No, Python doesn't exactly have this feature, but you can get very close.'

Comment: You can do `'''\ ` on the first line if the initial newline bothers you.  Sometimes we even do `''' something long '''.strip()` to remove the newlines.

Comment: Looks like just what I need :)